# Как получить текст с поле поиска или .keyup()

Tags: jquery, javascript

Делаю страничку картинок из flickr по тегам, и нужно чтобы картинки показывались так:

Есть поле: 
`<input id="flckr_input" type="text" >`
и если написать в поле  текст, например "Россия" то в div'е "#result_flickr" показывает картинки с тегом "Россия"

Сам я пробовал так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flckr_input").keyup(function() 
    {
    var rsltflk=$(this).val();
    var apiFlURL = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags='+rsltflk+'&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
    $.getJSON(apiFlURL,
            function(data){
              $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#result_flickr");
                if ( i == 5 ) return false;
           });
       }); 
     });
    });
```

Но этот код не сработал, понимаю не правильно все сделал, поправьте пожалуйста мой код, или объясните как правильно написать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу [@Романа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10590) - не DOSьте Flickr. У вас на каждое нажатие кнопки JSONP запрос! Есть удобное средство для подавления излишнего количества запросов в таких ситуациях: [throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/):  [http://jsfiddle.net/6cARt/](http://jsfiddle.net/6cARt/embedded/result/)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо. Прочитал полностью статью, задачу решил!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код [полностью рабочий](http://jsbin.com/uzewam/1) (я только добавил в callback функцию `$("#result_flickr").empty();` для очистки блока от предыдущих изображений). Значит проблема где-то ещё, смотрите консоль, возможно там есть ошибки javascript.